# createjs loadManifest, it should be loading files in manifest, correct?

Tags: createjs

If I understand the docs correctly…

```
window.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true, null, true);
queue.loadManifest({src: manifest, type: "manifest"}, true);
```

should be loading the files that are located in the json file, correct? Not seeing any requests in inspector, only getting the results array in console. Do I have to loop over results array and do the loadFile manually?

JSON is formatted correctly in a {src:"",id:"",type:"createjs.Types.IMAGE"} structure.

Any help is appreciated.

Adding more code:

**function to pass in manifest url**

```
function loadImages(manifest) {
    window.queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(true, null, true);

    queue.loadManifest({src: manifest, type: "manifest"}, true);

    queue.on("fileload", this.handleFileLoaded);

    queue.on("progress", function(event) {
        console.log("progress " + event.progress);
    });

    queue.on("fileprogress", function(event) {
        console.log("file progress " + event.progress);
    });

    queue.on("error", function(event) {
        console.log("file error");
    });

    queue.on("complete", function(event) {
        console.log("queue complete");
        console.log(event);
    });

    queue.load();

    return queue;
}
```

handleFileLoaded event is just dumping event to console at this point.

**Manifest with two examples**

```
{
    "path":"https://images.unsplash.com/",
    "type":"manifest",
    "manifest": [
        {
            "src":"photo-1542838454-d4dce2a7cfde?fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "id":"stair_boy",
            "type":"createjs.Types.IMAGE"
        },
        {
            "src":"photo-1549948558-1c6406684186?fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "id":"night_bridge",
            "type":"createjs.Types.IMAGE"
        }
]}
```

I get access to the manifest array in the fileload event, I can manually load the images from there, but that seems counterintuitive to the whole point of using the PreloadJS. Seems like on page load, Preload should load the manifest, recognize 'type'… loop through files and in network inspector I should see the web requests for the images.

Comment: Have you looked at the sample manifests in GitHub? Check out `_assets/static/MediaGridManifest.json` and the `ManifestTest.json`. https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/blob/master/_assets/static/ManifestTest.json -- Note that they are JSONP-formatted (wrapped in a function call and loaded as JavaScript) so they can load cross-domain, but the object structure should give you an idea on how it works. There is also an example that uses GitHub: https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/blob/master/examples/MediaGrid.html#L157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types in your manifest are incorrect. You are passing in a string value of "createjs.Types.IMAGE". This is not equal to "image", nor is it the equivalent of the JavaScript `createjs.Types.IMAGE`, since it is interpretted as a string.

Instead use the string value "image"

```
{
    "path":"https://images.unsplash.com/",
    "type":"manifest",
    "manifest": [
        {
            "src":"photo-1542838454-d4dce2a7cfde?fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "id":"stair_boy",
            "type":"image"
        },
        {
            "src":"photo-1549948558-1c6406684186?fit=crop&w=500&q=60",
            "id":"night_bridge",
            "type":"image"
        }
]}
```

Edit: The type property is only required when there is not a recognizable image extension, such as this case.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/classes/LoadQueue.html#method_loadManifest):

The `loadManifest` call supports four types of manifests:

1. A string path, which points to a manifest file, which is a JSON file that contains a "manifest" property, which defines the list of files to load, and can optionally contain a "path" property, which will be prepended to each file in the list.
2. An object which defines a "src", which is a JSON or JSONP file. A "callback" can be defined for JSONP file. The JSON/JSONP file should contain a "manifest" property, which defines the list of files to load, and can optionally contain a "path" property, which will be prepended to each file in the list.
3. An object which contains a "manifest" property, which defines the list of files to load, and can optionally contain a "path" property, which will be prepended to each file in the list.
4. An Array of files to load.

---

Your example uses the first approach. If something is not working, then feel free to post more code.

You could always throw some more events on your queue to see what is happening, such as "fileststart", "fileload", and "error". You should get at least one event when the first manifest starts loading.

Cheers.

Comment: Edited the original post to include main function and samples from manifest.